# Почему в ответ на второй запрос к google api search приходит ответ INVALID_REQUEST?

Tags: php, google-maps-api

Есть цикл **foreach**, в нем есть запрос (request google api search). При первой итерации запрос проходит нормально и статус - "ОК", вторая же итерация возвращает на запрос - "INVALID_REQUEST".

В чем может быть проблема? Возможно, сильно быстро обрабатываеться код, и стоит какой-то лимит на запрос?

Использую [библиотеку для Laravel 5](https://github.com/alexpechkarev/google-maps).

```
foreach (Place::PLACE_TYPES as $placeType) {
        $establishmentParams = [
            'location' => ['lat' => Place::MOSCOW_LAT, 'lng' => Place::MOSCOW_LNG],
            'language' => 'en',
            'types' => trans('places.place-type-' . $placeType),
            'radius' => 10000
        ];

        $pageToken = false;
        $response = "";
        $params = "";

        for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
            if (!$pageToken) {
                $params = $establishmentParams;
                $pageToken = true;
            } else {
                if (isset(json_decode($response)->next_page_token)) {
                    sleep(2);
                    $params = ['pagetoken' => json_decode($response)->next_page_token];
                }
            }

            $response = \GoogleMaps::load('nearbysearch')->setParam($params)->get();

            if ($placeType == 2) {
                dd($response);
            }
            if (json_decode($response)->status == trans('places.status-' . Place::STATUS_OK)) {
                $result = json_decode($response)->results;
                for ($x = 0; $x < 1; $x++) {
                    $getPlaceDetails = \GoogleMaps::load('placedetails')
                        ->setParam(['placeid' => $result[$x]->place_id, 'language' => 'en'])
                        ->get();
                    if (json_decode($getPlaceDetails)->status == trans('places.status-' . Place::STATUS_OK)) {
                        $placeDetails = json_decode($getPlaceDetails)->result;
                        $place['formatted_phone_number'] = $placeDetails->formatted_phone_number;
                        if (isset($placeDetails->opening_hours)) {
                            $place['opening_hours'] = json_encode($placeDetails->opening_hours);
                        }
                        $place['type'] = $placeType;
                        $place['name'] = $result[$x]->name;
                        $place['google_id'] = $result[$x]->id;
                        $place['place_id'] = $result[$x]->place_id;
                        if (isset($result[$x]->rating)) {
                            $place['rating'] = $result[$x]->rating;
                        }
                        if (isset($result[$x]->price_level)) {
                            $place['price_level'] = $result[$x]->price_level;
                        }
                        $place['formatted_address'] = $placeDetails->formatted_address;
                        $place['location_lat'] = $result[$x]->geometry->location->lat;
                        $place['location_lng'] = $result[$x]->geometry->location->lng;
                        $place['icon'] = $result[$x]->icon;
                        $place['google_json_data'] = json_encode($result[$x]);
                        Place::create($place);
                    } else {
                        $this->error(json_decode($getPlaceDetails)->status);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $this->error(json_decode($response)->status);
                break;
            }
        }
        $this->info(trans('places.place-type-' . $placeType) . ' places has been imported!');
    }
```

Comment: На самом деле, причина может быть в частоте запроса и количестве вызовов за секунду.

Comment: Или Вы не там делаете инициализацию токена

Comment: А также в кодировке. Убедитесь, что параметры запроса в UTF8

Comment: Присойденяюсь к @cyadvert. Может быть даже проблема в кодировке файла. И используйте `iconv()` для перекодировки текста.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос оба URL запроса, пожалуйста

Comment: А также добавьте как Вы обращаетесь циклом к API

Comment: @Roman Kozin добавил

Comment: Попробуйте сделать `URL::Encode::url_encode_utf8($address);`

Comment: @Roman Kozin, а при чем сдесь $address?

Comment: Это адрес, который Вы ищете

Comment: Просто при первой итерации возвращает все ок, результаты есть, а тут в коде когла я делаю 
if ($placeType == 2) {
                dd($response);}
уже invalid request от google

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34987/discussion-between-islam-khandurdyiev-and-roman-kozin).

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в библиотеке. Там static переменная которая отвечает за параметры, не перезаписываться (не обнуляеться) после использования определенного api.
у меня в коде

```
$getPlaceDetails = \GoogleMaps::load('placedetails')
                    ->setParam(['placeid' => $result[$x]->place_id, 'language' => 'en'])
                    ->get();
```

используеться сервис placedetails, и когда я его использую, переменная с параметрами остаеться та же, которая не подходит для использования нового сервиса nearbysearch, при переходе на новую итерацию. Pull request с исправлениями отправил на репозиторий библиотеки.